# How to create a unique deferrable constraint with timestamp cast to date expression in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

PostgreSQL 11.1

AFAIK, a constraint can not be based on an expression. So what is the best way of achieving this in PostgreSQL 11.1? (I'm hoping this has improved since 9.2);

```
ALTER TABLE dx
ADD CONSTRAINT dx_unique UNIQUE ((tposted::date))
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

TIA

Comment: You could use an index on an expression `date_trunc('day',tposted)` , but it cannot be DEFERRED. Or, you could use a *cloned* DATE column, shadowing the timestamp.

Comment: @wildplasser -- what about an immutable function?

Comment: @AlanWayne how did you resolve it?